# Python Attribute Error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, tuples, attributeerror

My code keeps having the same error and I have tried a few ways to fix it but none have worked can anyone help me with it?
The code:

```
def main():
    p.init()
    screen = p.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    clock = p.time.Clock()
    screen.fill(p.Color("white"))
    gs = GameState()
    LoadImages()
    running= True
    sqselected = ()
    playerClicks = ()
    while running:
        for e in p.event.get():
            if e.type == p.QUIT:
                running = False
            elif e.type == p.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                location = p.mouse.get_pos()
                col = location[0]//SQSIZE
                row = location[1]//SQSIZE
                if sqselected == (row,col):
                    sqselected = ()
                    playerClicks = []
                else:
                    sqselected= (row, col)
                    playerClicks.append(sqselected)
                if len(playerClicks)==2:
                    move = Move(playerClicks[0], playerClicks[1], gs.board)
                    print(Move.getChessNotation())
                    gs.Makemove(move)
                    sqselected = ()
                    playerClicks = []
```

Comment: Do you know which line is causing the error?

Comment: Where is `sqselected` initially defined? I'm wondering if your code somehow skips to the `else` statement and that `playerClicks` is defined as a tuple elsewhere in your code.

Comment: The error line is 'playerClicks.append(sqselected).

Comment: And sqselected is initially defined at sqselected = ()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The first initialization of `playerClicks` is as a tuple:

```
playerClicks = ()
```

but later it's set to an empty list:

```
playerClicks = []
```

You can't append to a tuple, because once they're created they can't be changed.

If you change the first initialization to an empty list that would allow appending to it.